# latlon format for cloudsearch

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudsearch

I want to do Geographic search in cloud search, I do indexing like this:

[image]

when I uploading document

```
[{"type": "add", "id": "kdhrlfh1304532987654321987654321", "fields":{"name": "user1", "latlon":[12.628611, 120.694152] , "phoneverifiedon": "2015-05-04T15:39:03Z", "fbnumfriends": 172}},
{"type": "add", "id": "kdhrlfh1304532987654321987654322", "fields": {"name": "user2", "latlon":[12.628645,20.694178] , "phoneverifiedon": "2015-05-04T15:39:03Z", "fbnumfriends": 172}}]
```

I got below error

```
Status: error
Adds: 0
Deletes: 0
Errors:
{ ["Field "latlon" must have array type to have multiple values (near operation with index 1; document_id kdhrlfh1304532987654321987654321)","Validation error for field 'latlon': Invalid latlon value 12.628611"] }
```

I tried multiple format for "**latlon**" field
please suggest what is the correct format for the lat long in  cloudsearch

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax for doc submission is a single string with the two values comma-separated, eg `"latlon" : "12.628611, 120.694152"`.

```
[
  {
    "type": "add",
    "id": "kdhrlfh1304532987654321987654321",
    "fields": {
      "name": "user1",
      "latlon" : "12.628611, 120.694152"
      "phoneverifiedon": "2015-05-04T15:39:03Z",
      "fbnumfriends": 172
    }
  }
]
```

It is definitely confusing that the submission syntax doesn't match the query syntax, which uses an array to represent lat-lon.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=151633

Comment: Thanks for Ans
how can  i add ProfileCredentialsProvider to the AmazonCloudSearchClient     like we add for dynamoDB

Comment: Thanks for Ans
how can  i add ProfileCredentialsProvider to the AmazonCloudSearchClient     like we do for dynamoDB
I make  a user  **John**  in  AWS and  give permission for CloudSearchFullAccess,   But i m not getting how to add profile name (John) to AmazonCloudSearchClient,  currently i m getting Access Denied Error

Comment: That's a very different problem; please ask a new question. But first please read the relevant docs because the answer is out there.

Comment: What about multiple locations, could I have something like `"latlon" : ["12.628611, 120.694152", "12.628611, 120.694152", "12.628611, 120.694152"]` and still use locations ranking?

Comment: @user2976753 no, there is no field type for an array of latlons http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-index-fields.html . As an aside, please open a new question when you have a new question.